# How to import ipynb to py?

Tags: python, matplotlib, import, jupyter-notebook

I need to import ipynb containing matplotlib to py.

```
import import_ipynb
import proj1
```

I get error:

> NotImplementedError: Implement enable_gui in a subclass.

How can I fix it?